# No Android Project available

Tags: java, android, eclipse, macos, project

I am running Lion 10.7.3 in MacBookPro.  I have installed Eclipse, SDK and ADT.

When I choose File->New, there are only Java Project and Project but no Android Project is available.

Anybody encounter this problem before?  How can I solve it?  Any link for instructions?

Comment: How exactly did you install the ADT Eclipse plugin?

Answer (score 0):

Try `File`->`New`->`Project`->`Android`->`Android project`.

Answer (score 0):

File -> New -> Other (bottom of list) -> Android -> Android Project